# Select values of noise contours along one road

Tags: arcgis-pro, select, contour, road

I have a map of noise contours across a city and am using ArcGIS Pro.

I want to select one road (not straight) and export the noise values along that road to a table but I'm having trouble selecting the road.

Is it better to draw a curved line or should I create a polygon - and because it's just one area I want to "arbitrarily" select on the map, how can I manually do this? And how to do it so that I can extract the noise values it intersects with?

The problem is I only have the noise layer on the basemap. I don't think I have any attributes of the road.

I'm new to GIS. I've searched online and can't find anything that helps.

Comment: Using two logins to ask the same question in two different threads can cause editing difficulty. Please use only one login.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to select the road by attribute, maybe by the name or some other unique identifier. Then under the Selection Options, change your selection type to "Remove from current selection" and deselect all of the road segments outside of your boundary. Then choose "Select by Location." Your input features are the noise values, your selecting features will be the road layer with your selected road segments, and the relationship will be "Intersect" and your choice of any search distances if desired (maybe like 20ft to account for road width if the noise layer doesn't perfectly intersect with the road). Click OK. You should see your nearby noise features highlighted. Right click the noise layer, select data, and export to table.